# Chrome Script Blackbox not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

The debugger is pausing without breakpoint in libraries like jquery on page load
the warning message is shown that the script is blackboxed but ironically the debugger stops there.

Please suggest if i have to do something more than blackboxing in order to prevent debugger pauses in library scripts

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem and hate it....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug.
Is there any pause reason printed in the "Call Stack" sidebar pane (above the "Scope Variables")?
Maybe you could file a bug report at http://crbug.com/new ?

Answer (score 0):

In summary, try deactivate breakpoints in Chrome dev tools (counter intuitive I know but it works for me).

Am using Dojo and find the blackboxing feature invaluable. It used to work reliably on an older version of Chrome for me, but for a colleague with the same version it didn't.

Recently my Chrome upgraded to Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit) and the blackboxing behaviour stopped working reliably for me. My most common use case is to be able to click on a button and have it skip all the Dojo code so Chrome starts debugging at the first non-blackboxed piece of application code it hits (app logic often hidden behind hitch closures).

I would cue this up as follows:

- Navigate to page with button in app
- Open Chrome dev tools
- Hover over button in app
- Hit F8 to tell Chrome to break on next code to fire
- Click button in app
- Chrome should enter debug at the first non-blackboxed piece of code

However Chrome would start debugging blackboxed code (it would even state the code is blackboxed in a banner atop the code!).

By default I would always have Chrome breakpoints active. By chance I tried the above with Chrome breakpoints deactivated (CTRL+F8) and repeated the above and it fixed the blackboxing behaviour.

My blackboxing rules are: `\.*dojo/d\.*`

Answer (score -1):

If you close out the file from the editor window it should not open back up when it is blackboxed. If you keep it open however, it will still break in the file. If it is still opening up then yes, that would be a bug and should be filed.